# How to pass a SOAP envelope to a web service method that expects an Object

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I am passing an XML string inside a soap envelope, the web service method expects an object as parameter, to its some internal class that is having the same structure as the XML and the client has no idea about this class. I need the object to be filled from the XML string. I am using `HttpWebRequest` to achieve this, but had no luck as of now.

Client Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(url);
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><" + methodName + " xmlns='http://xsp.com/module'><MyClass><strXML xsi:type='xsd:string'>" + xml + "</strXML></MyClass></" + methodName + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
}
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();                    
    }
}
```

Web Service Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestMethod(MyClass myClass)
{
    if (myClass == null)
        return "myClass is null";
    if (myClass.strXML == null)
    {               
        return "myclass.strXML is null";                
    }            
    return myClass.strXML.toString();
}

public class MyClass
{
    private object sXML;        
    public object strXML
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sXML;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sXML = value;
        }
    }        
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does no luck mean? It ends with an error, or the result is wrong?

Comment: I meant how the TestMethod MyClass parameter will be filled from the XML string passed within the soap envelope from the client. Right now the MyClass parameter in the TestMethod is null. So, how the deserialization from XML to MyClass parameter will happen, so that it can get populated correctly?